# Convert SQL to Eloquent to Join multiple table and Count

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel-5, eloquent

I have been this SQL working fine, but trying to convert it to Eloquent format, it keeps returning a wrong, SQL entirely which flags error. 
Coding with Laravel 5.5

```
Select arm_articles.article_topic, arm_articles.id, arm_articles.article_id, 
COUNT(arm_article_views.view_article_id) AS TotalViews, 
COUNT( arm_article_likes.liked_article_id) AS TotalLikes, 
COUNT( arm_article_comments.comment_article_id) AS TotalComments
FROM arm_articles 
LEFT JOIN  arm_article_views  ON  arm_articles.article_id = arm_article_views.view_article_id 
LEFT JOIN  arm_article_likes  ON  arm_articles.article_id = arm_article_likes.liked_article_id 
LEFT JOIN  arm_article_comments  ON  arm_articles.article_id = arm_article_comments.comment_article_id 
GROUP BY arm_articles.article_id 
ORDER BY TotalLikes, TotalLikes, TotalComments ASC`
```

**HOW I MADE ELOQUENT QUERY BUILDER** Not working though:

```
return Datatables::of(PostModel::leftJoin('arm_article_views', 'arm_article_views.view_article_id', '=', 'arm_articles.article_id')
       ->leftJoin('arm_article_likes','arm_article_likes.liked_article_id', '=', 'arm_articles.article_id')
       ->leftJoin('arm_article_comments', 'arm_article_comments.comment_article_id','=','arm_articles.article_id')
       ->selectRaw(
           'arm_articles.*, 
           count(arm_article_views.view_article_id) AS ViewCount'
        ) 
        ->groupBy('arm_articles.article_id')->orderBy('ViewCount','DESC')
        ->where('arm_articles.article_contributor_id','=',$contributor_id)
        ->getQuery())->make(true);
```

Any hint would be appreciated

Comment: @Nikola Gavric  do u have a clue ?

Comment: I've posted an answer, awaiting for you to see if it did the trick

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

```
DB::table('arm_articles')
        ->leftJoin('arm_article_views', 'arm_articles.article_id', '=', 'arm_article_views.view_article_id')
        ->leftJoin('arm_article_likes', 'arm_articles.article_id', '=', 'arm_article_likes.liked_article_id')
        ->leftJoin('arm_article_comments', 'arm_articles.article_id', '=', 'arm_article_comments.comment_article_id')
        ->groupBy('arm_articles.article_id', 'article_topic')
        ->select(
            DB::raw('count(arm_article_views.view_article_id) as TotalViews'),
            DB::raw('count(arm_article_likes.liked_article_id) as TotalLikes'),
            DB::raw('count(arm_article_comments.comment_article_id) as TotalComments'),
            'arm_articles.article_id',
            'article_topic'
        )->get();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i ran into some SQL error when i try adding more field on the select  `->select('arm_articles.*',`

Error message
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'knowledge_db.arm_articles.id' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select `arm_articles`.*, count(arm_article_views.view_article_id) as TotalViews, count(arm_article_likes.liked_article_id) as TotalLikes, count(arm_article_comments.comment_a.........

Comment: DB::table('arm_articles')->leftJoin('arm_article_views', 'arm_articles.article_id', '=', 'arm_article_views.view_article_id')->leftJoin('arm_article_likes', 'arm_articles.article_id', '=', 'arm_article_likes.liked_article_id')->leftJoin('arm_article_comments', 'arm_articles.article_id', '=', 'arm_article_comments.comment_article_id')->groupBy('arm_articles.article_id')->select('arm_articles.*',DB::raw('count(arm_article_views.view_article_id) as TotalViews'),DB::raw('count(arm_article_likes.liked_article_id) as TotalLikes'),DB::raw('count(arm_article_comments.comment_article_id) as ....

Comment: You are grouping by `article_id` so you cannot use `*` wildcard

Comment: I tried using 
`->select('arm_articles.id','arm_articles.article_id','arm_articles.article_category_id','arm_articles.article_topic','arm_articles.article_type','arm_articles.article_date','arm_articles.article_active','arm_articles.article_category','arm_articles.article_tag',` and it returned same error



Or how do i include the article_id and the article_topic to the selected fields in the SQL

Comment: Just ran your updated SQL and got error `SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'knowledge_db.arm_articles.article_topic' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select count(arm_article_views.view_article_id) as TotalViews, count(arm_article_likes.liked_article_id) as TotalLikes,`  => seems like once you add any field to the select, it flags

Comment: I updated my code once again, take a look at `groupBy` since it contains another column `title` in this groupBy

Comment: Code works.... but i seem not to agree with the result the SQL is pulling out for me.. http://prntscr.com/ie5wd4

Comment: Then you need to fetch `counters` in one query and `topic names` in another one, because grouping by `title name` in this query is not gonna work

Comment: I think the issue here is with the `groupBy` in Laravel Eloquent. cos i just tried another SQL, applying the groupBy works as an SQL but converting it to Eloquent just flags error.... a Bug i think..

Cos till now, i am yet to get the right Query to make it work