# GroupBy Error in Laravel Eloquent Builder

Tags: php, laravel, group-by, eloquent

I dont want to believe there is a bug in laravel 5.5 cos i am amazed how i keep getting errors on the Eloquent Query Builder when ever i use the groupBy in my query.

Tried converting this SQL that works seamlessly to Eloquent and i keep getting Errors on the groupBy..

Had a similar issue with an SQL which i complained here and till now i have not gotten a perfect answer for it
[open issue here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48765310/convert-sql-to-eloquent-to-join-multiple-table-and-count)

```
SELECT * FROM arm_articles
    INNER JOIN arm_interest ON arm_articles.article_category = arm_interest.category_id 
    WHERE arm_articles.article_contributor_id='1322' 
    GROUP BY arm_articles.article_id
```

**ELOQUENT VERSION THAT RETURNS ERROR**

```
$contributor_id =1322;
DB::table('arm_articles')
->join('arm_interest', function($join) {
    $join->on('arm_articles.article_category','=','arm_interest.category_id');
})
->having('arm_articles.article_contributor_id', '=', $contributor_id)
->groupBy('arm_articles.article_id')->get()
```

**ERROR MESSAGE**

`SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'knowledge_db.arm_articles.id' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select * from 'arm_articles' inner join 'arm_interest' on 'arm_articles'.'article_category' = 'arm_interest'.'category_id' group by 'arm_articles'.'article_id' having 'arm_articles'.'article_contributor_id' = 1322)`

So like i said b4 its really weared why i will get the error in the first place as adding `->toSql` to the query returns the right SQL.

Answer (score 1):

- Add this configuration to your mysql database config in `config/database.php`:

  ```
     'mysql' => [
          ....
          'strict' => false,
          //'strict' => true,
      ],
  ```
- Edit `sql_mode` in your mysql config file (`my.ini` or `my.cnf`)
  [mysqld]

  ```
  sql_mode = STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
  ```
- Restart your MySQL

Comment: Thanks for you heads-up.
Lets say i am running this application online, How do i have access to the `sql_mode`  settings if i am on a shared hosting account ?

Comment: Try only updating `database.php` config

Comment: `'mysql' => [
        ....
        'strict' => false,
        //'strict' => true,
    ],`

Did the trick for me..

Thanks a bunch