# laravel eloquent error , I can not get created_at use groupBy method

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am trying to get max value and create at date with groupBy method.

But when I put the created_at column, I got an error.

```
    $rankings = Ranking
        ::select(DB::raw('MAX(rankings.percentage_correct_answer) as percentage_correct_answer, rankings.user_id,rankings.created_at'))
        ->groupBy('rankings.user_id')
        ->get();
```

errors:

**SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'app.rankings.created_at' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select MAX(rankings.percentage_correct_answer) as percentage_correct_answer, rankings.user_id,rankings.created_at from `rankings` where `rankings`.`deleted_at` is null group by `rankings`.`user_id`)**

However, I did fine by pulling out the created_at column. Why?

And I want to get the created_at column, what should I do?

No error this code.

```
    $rankings = Ranking
        ::select(DB::raw('MAX(rankings.percentage_correct_answer) as percentage_correct_answer, rankings.user_id'))
        ->groupBy('rankings.user_id')
        ->get();
```

Model code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;


class Ranking extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;
    protected $table = 'rankings';
    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id','percentage_correct_answer'
    ];
}
```

rankings table description:

```
+---------------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                     | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                        | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| user_id                   | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| percentage_correct_answer | int(11)             | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at                | timestamp           | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at                | timestamp           | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| deleted_at                | timestamp           | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+---------------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Comment: When using `groupBy`, all the non-aggregated columns should be exclude from `select`. or need to find a way to aggregate those columns.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Tharaka!

I tried add database config in config/database.php:

```
'mysql' => [
        ....
        'strict' => false,
        //'strict' => true,
    ],
```

Then it works.

I referred to this question.

**[GroupBy Error in Laravel Eloquent Builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48789627/groupby-error-in-laravel-eloquent-builder)**

But I don't really understand the cause of the error.